# nose2 vs nose test discovery (nose2 not finding tests)

Tags: python-2.7, nose, nosetests

I just started a python project and I'm trying out different test frameworks.
The problem I have is that nose2 does not find my tests:

> $ nose2 --verbose
>
> ---
>
> Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
>
> OK

while nosetests find them all

> $ nosetests --collect-only
>
> .................................
>
> ---
>
> Ran 33 tests in 0.004s
>
> OK

Otherwhise I can execute a single test with nose2 from same directory:

> $ nose2 myproj.client.test.mypkg.mymodule_test
>
> .
>
> ---
>
> Ran 1 test in 0.007s
>
> OK

where myproj.client.test.mypkg.mymodule_test is like:

```
'''
Created on 18/04/2013

@author: julia
'''
from unittest import TestCase, main
import os
from myproj.client.mymodule import SUT
from mock import Mock
import tempfile

class SUTTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.folder = tempfile.mkdtemp(suffix='myproj')
        self.sut = SUT(self.folder, Mock())
        self.sut.init()

    def test_wsName(self):
        myfolder = os.path.join(self.folder, 'myfolder')
        os.mkdir(myfolder)
        self.sut.change_dir(myfolder)
        self.assertEquals(self.SUT.name, 'myfolder')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've been looking at documentation and I cannot find a possible cause for this.

Running python 2.7.3 on MacOs 10.8.3

Comment: Try run `nose2` with `--verbose` option - you should see why is it skipping your tests.

Comment: same result :/ (no verbosity output)

Comment: Can you list some of your test code?

Answer (score 6):

Adding to MichaelJCox's answer, another problem is that nose2, by default, is looking for your test file names to begin with 'test'.  In other words, '`testFilePattern == test*.py`' (you can find that in `nose2/session.py`).

You can fix this in two ways:

### Specify a different test file pattern in a configuration file:

Create a configuration file somewhere in your project (the base directory is a good place, or wherever you will run nose2).  nose2 will look for and load any file called `nose2.cfg` or `unittest.cfg`.

Add this to that configuration file.

```
[unittest]
test-file-pattern=*.py
```

Now run nose2 again and it'll find those old test cases.  I'm unsure if this could adversely affect nose2 performance or what, but so far so good for me.

### Rename your test files so that they begin with test.

For example, if you have a project like this:

```
/tests/
      __init__.py
      fluxcapacitor.py
```

Rename `/tests/fluxcapacitor.py` to `/tests/test_fluxcapacitor.py`, now nose2 will find the tests inside fluxcapacitor.py again.

### More verbose output

Finally, this is unrelated to your question but might be helpful in the future: If `-verbose` doesn't output enough info, you can also pass the following additional arg `--log-level debug` for even more output.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like nose2 needs 1 of 3 things to find the test:

1. Your tests need to be in packages (just create __init__.py files in each dir of your   test structure)
2. You need a directory named 'test' in the same directory in which nose2 is being run
3. It needs to be in the same directory

nose2's _discovery method (in nose2.plugins.loader.discovery.py) is explicitly looking for directories named 'test' or directories that are packages (if it doesn't just pick up your test files from the same directory):

```
            if ('test' in path.lower()
                or util.ispackage(entry_path)
                or path in self.session.libDirs):
                for test in self._find_tests(event, entry_path, top_level):
                    yield test
```

If I set up a similar test file (called tests.py) and run nose2 in the same directory, it gives me the 1 test OK back.

If I create a directory named 'test', move the file to it, and run nose2 from the top directory, I get an error stating that it can't import my py file. Creating an __init__.py in that directory fixes that error.

If I make a directory 'blah' instead and move the file there, then I see the issue you list above:

```
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

However, if I then create an __init__.py in directory 'blah', the test runs and I get my 1 test found and OK'd.

Comment: I have __init__ .py files in all my dirs but yeah, test folders are not in top level directory but per package. However if I descend into myproj/client (which contains a test package) and execute nose2 there I still get 0 tests but thanks anyway, I'll stick with nosetest

Comment: the __init__.py was the solution for me